# how to prevent multiple object creation using reflection

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection

i have method that is used to return the instance of the object. Using reflection am getting the class instance that's fine.
 i need to avoid creating a new object every time for the same class.
Do i missing something??

```
private static Object getInstance(String clazz) 
{
    //full path of the class in the clazz

    Class<?> c = null;
    Object obj = null;

    try 
    {
        c = Class.forName(clazz);
        System.out.println("inside ins" + c);
        obj = c.newInstance();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return obj;
}

Object inst = getInstance("com.test.Test1");
Method method = inst.getClass().getMethod("getVal", String.class,String.class);
method.invoke(inst, "new params","ss");
```

thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need a `Map<String, Object>` as a cache, basically...

Comment: You can check instanceOf method.

Comment: ...or use IoC container

Comment: Can the objects you want to return be implemented as singletons? You can then use reflection to access the specified class's getInstance() method

Comment: yes if it can be done its great @ewanc

Comment: Why do you want singletons? Why do you want to use reflection? Both are usually a bad idea...

Comment: the use of reflection is i have multiple class instances used across the application so each time i need to write like `   private static ClassOne instance;

   `public static ClassOne getInstance() {
      if (instance==null) {
         instance = new ClassOne();
      }
      return instance;
   }`
this leads my code to grow if i use reflection it will behave like a template so just pass the class location will give an obj instance
2) If i focus to use like a template i need to strictly validate that if the object is already exists i need to return that obj rather than creating a new one

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could proceed:

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<String, FutureTask<Object>> INSTANCES = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private static Object getInstance(String clazz) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {//full path of the class in the clazz
    FutureTask<Object> task = new FutureTask<>(() -> Class.forName(clazz).newInstance());
    FutureTask<Object> previous = INSTANCES.putIfAbsent(clazz, task);
    if (previous == null) {
        task.run();
    } else {
        task = previous;
    }
    return task.get();
}
```

Here is the same code but for Java 1.7

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<String, FutureTask<Object>> INSTANCES = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private static Object getInstance(final String clazz) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {//full path of the class in the clazz
    FutureTask<Object> task = new FutureTask<>(new Callable<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            return Class.forName(clazz).newInstance();
        }
    });
    FutureTask<Object> previous = INSTANCES.putIfAbsent(clazz, task);
    if (previous == null) {
        task.run();
    } else {
        task = previous;
    }
    return task.get();
}
```

Comment: i guess you implemented with JRE 1.8 can you propose me for JRE 1.7? i guess lambda is started only from 1.8

Comment: Version for Java 1.7 added

Comment: What a ridiculously overcomplicated way to solve a simple problem.

Comment: @Kayaman Sorry to hear that please provide a better answer then any help is always welcome

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Is there any reason for the `Future`, `Callable` and `ConcurrentMap` besides trying to show off? The question doesn't even mention concurrency, after all.

Comment: @Kayaman the title starts with "how to prevent multiple object creation", if you propose a solution without thinking of concurrency your answer is simply wrong because otherwise you will still be able to create multiple instances of the same object by calling concurrently the method with the same class name

Comment: @NicolasFilotto With English most likely not being your first language, he was referring to "singleton-ness" (due to calling `newInstance()` every time the method is called) and not concurrency. While concurrency may also become an issue depending on his context, it's not nearly as much an issue as your answer suggests.

Comment: @Kayaman If you don't like my answer simply vote down, but please don't insult people trying to help for free

Comment: Downvoting is for wrong answers, not for "not liking them". I was just curious about the massive concurrency code. Where did I insult you? Is English your first language? If so, pardon for my assumption.

Comment: "ridiculously" doesn't sound to me like a nice word and yes about my english, indeed it is not my native language but I do my best sorry if it is not enough for you

Comment: guys calm down this place is to help among ourselves rather than competing to each other we can learn something from others so help each other we ll grow along

Comment: for JRE 1.7 how to fix this . I have also commented in the question for your reference

Comment: Check the code snippet after "Here is the same code but for Java 1.7" in my answer

Comment: @NicolasFilotto 
1) Object inst = getInstance("com.test.Test1");-> will create a new instance 
2)Object inst1 = getInstance("com.test.Test");-> will create a new instance
3) Object inst2 = getInstance("com.test.Test1");-> the previous is still null and unable to proceed further ?

Comment: @Rathishkumar My code was incorrect, I forgot to run the task, try again with the new code. About your question, no you will get the same instance, you will get the instance returned by the FutureTask at each call, the FutureTask is executed only once. To check simply call System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(getInstance("myClass"))); several times you should get the same value

Comment: @NicolasFilotto when i execute the line am getting stack overflow error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Do you call getInstance somewhere in the constructor of the object that you try to create with this method? If not could you please provide the stack trace and the code of the class that you test?

Comment: @Rathishkumar Is it ok now? If not could you please answer my questions in the previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility here would be to implement the classes you want to return as singletons. Then in your getInstance() method you can invoke the getInstance() method (or whatever you want to call it) of the singleton. So for example, your singleton class would look something like this:

```
public class ClassOne {

   private static ClassOne instance;

   public static ClassOne getInstance() {
      if (instance==null) {
         instance = new ClassOne();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

And your getInstance() method would be modified to look something like this. (Please note this code has not been tested, but I have done exactly this before so the principle definitely does work)

```
private static Object getInstance(String clazz) {//full path of the class in the clazz
    Class<?> c = null;
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        c = Class.forName(clazz);
        System.out.println("inside ins" + c);
        Method method = c.getMethod("getInstance", null);
        obj = method.invoke(null, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

So you are essentially just delegating control of when a new instance is created to the class itself. Depending on the classes you want to invoke in this way it might be possible to abstract the singleton behaviour into a separate class that you can inherit, but this can be a little tricky when using reflection like this.